# executing python code/function as stored procedure in mssql..?

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

Is there a way to save the python code/ function as stored procedure in mssql server,

I have created a dataframe by retrieving data from database (MSSQL) then created a function to manipulate the data based on certain conditions, but I need to perform this on a weekly basis. If I could store this code as stored procedure in mssql server..this can be done, i guess, 
is there a way to do this, or any alternative ways are welcome?

Comment: "Is there a way to save the python code/ function as stored procedure in mssql server" Short answer: No. What are you doing with the DataFrame once you've "manipulated" it? Sending it back to the SQL Server? Also, have you investigated whether the transformations you are performing could be done using T-SQL instead of Python?

Comment: @GordThompson I am using python to loop through the records to just change the numbers  based on conditions, and I want to perform it on a weekly basis automatically.. I have checked the T-SQL, for me python is more convenient to do the task.. also python provides all relevant functions for that..

Comment: You should look into porting the code to MSSQL. Python may be more convenient, but with a little research you should be able to accomplish everything you need.

Comment: @robbpriestley thank you very much, I will try that..